# No viable conversion from returned value of type 'double' to function return type 'vector<double>'

Tags: c++

I don't know how to convert the variable type int to vector.

```
vector<double> movingTiles(int l, int s1, int s2, vector<int> queries) {
double smalld, t;
for(int i=0;i<queries.size();i++){
    smalld = sqrt(2*queries[i]);
    if(s2>s1){
        t=(sqrt(2)*l-smalld)/(s2-s1);
        return t;
    }else{
        t=(sqrt(2)*l-smalld)/(s2-s1);
        return t;
    }
}}
```

Comment: vector isn't a data type - it is a container.

Comment: Why is your return type `vector<double>`, if you want to return just a single number? Simply use `double` as a return type.

Comment: Use `return {t};` if you want for some reason return vector with one element.

Comment: I think he doesn't want to return a single value...

Comment: Here is the link to the problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-moving-tiles/problem

Comment: The function `return` statements all return `t`, which is of type `double`.   As the error message says, there is no implicit conversion from a `double` to a `vector<double>`.  I assume you have a `using` directive (not shown) in effect, so `vector<double>` is actually `std::vector<double>`.   `std::vector<double>` does not have a constructor that accepts a single argument of type `double`.   If you want to return a vector with one element, where that element has the value of `t`, then do `return vector<double>(1, t)`.

Comment: Turns out the boilerpalate code was wrong so I rewrote the code form scratch. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the link in your comment:

> For **each** query of form ***q**i*, Sherlock has to report the time at which the overlapping area of tiles is equal to ***q**i*.

This leads me to believe that the output vector should have the same size as the input vector `queries`, so:

```
vector<double> movingTiles(int l, int s1, int s2, vector<int> queries) {
    double smalld, t;
    // the vector to return:
    vector<double> times;
    // reserve space to make push_backs quicker:
    times.reserve(queries.size());

    // you only need to calculate this once for each set of queries
    int rspeed = std::abs(s1 - s2); // the absolute diff in speed

    for(int area : queries) {
        // your formula:
        smalld = sqrt(2 * area);
        t = (sqrt(2) * l - smalld) / rspeed;
        // store the result
        times.push_back(t);
    }

    // and return the resulting vector:
    return times;
}
```

Comment: Better to use vector constructor that takes `queries.size()` as input, or use `reserve()`

Comment: @CinCout-ReinstateMonica for small datasets  I doubt it'll have any measureable effect, but I agree that it's a good habit. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You should `return std::vector<double>(1, t)` from the method if you want to return a `vector`

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess, but that what you want is this I think:

```
vector<double> movingTiles(int l, int s1, int s2, vector<int> queries) {
    double smalld, t; 
    vector<double> vec_t;
    for(int i=0;i<queries.size();i++){
        smalld = sqrt(2*queries[i]);
        if(s2>s1){
            t=(sqrt(2)*l-smalld)/(s2-s1);
            vec_t.push_back(t);
        }else{
            t=(sqrt(2)*l-smalld)/(s2-s1);
            vec_t.push_back(t);
        }
    }
    return vec_t;
}
```